# Huge image resample on the fly

Tags: image

I have a huge image (234 megapixels) I want to plot in a way that it is dynamically resampled depending on the size of the area the user wishes to see. Is there any tool that supports doing this, or will I need to do this myself?

Comment: By plot are you refering to image tiling? (http://star.pst.qub.ac.uk/idl/Image_Tiling.html)

Comment: I was thinking about rendering the entire image downsampled and load the area the user wants to see as they need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the techniques to do this are referred to as (Image) Tile Rendering.  Basically this is how applications such as Google Maps work.

A quick search on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=image%20tiling%20library) turned up an OpenGL library for doing this for you (http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/TR.html).  I'm sure there are others that you should be able to discover if this library doesn't fit your technology needs.